# return a typedef type when using separate compilation

Tags: c++, class, vector, typedef, typename

Here are the files I am working on:

class.h

```
#include <vector>

using std::vector;

template<class T>
class test {
private:
    vector<T> data;

public:

    typedef vector<T> vt;
    typedef typename vt::iterator it;

    test() {
    }
    ;
    it find(T x);
}
```

and class.cpp

```
#include "class.h"

it test::find(T x) {
    return find(data.begin(), data.end(), x);
}
```

The codes work if I put the implementation of find inside the class declaration.

However, when I separate the implementation from the class, the compiler reports an error "expected initializer before test".

How to fix it? Is the problem related to the scope of typedef/typename?

Sorry for my poor English, it is my secondary language.

Please point out any error in my codes as well as my english

Thank you for your help.:D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the compiler sees `it`, it can't yet know that you mean `test<T>::it`. So you have to tell it:

```
template<class T> typename test<T>::it test<T>::find(T x) {
    // The following line doesn't compile, but that's another issue:
    // return find(data.begin(), data.end(), x);
}
```

See http://ideone.com/Rtho2 for a working program.

Answer (score 0):

Now templates in C++ violates this principle, bcoz C++ is a compiled language. And compiler generates all the needed code during compilation. Now to adhere to OOP we end up with fragile templates which not 100% generic in nature.

**Keep declaration and definitions separate (SHARING implementation)**

If you are just want to keep things clean and in order, then you can include your implementation file in another header. I think it should be header file as this goes with basic convention that we share .h files and we keep .cc files not to be shared (until you are sharing the code itself). Here is how the files look.

**foo.h**

This is simple file with including `foo_impl.h`.

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H
template <class T>
class Foo {
  public:
    Foo (T);
    T get();
  private:
    T data;
};

#include "foo_impl.h"
#endif
```

**foo_impl.h**

This one is bit different from the norms. Here we are not guarding the header file content. Instead we will raise an error if some one included `foo_impl.h` directly (which in our case does not make sense).

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#error 'foo_impl.h' is not supposed to be included directly. Include 'foo.h' instead.
#endif

template <class T>
Foo <T> :: Foo (T stuff) {
   data = stuff;
}

template <class T>
T Foo <T> :: get () {
   return data;
}
```

Now if some one tries to include `foo_impl.h` directly will get error like:

```
foo_impl.h:2:2: error: #error 'foo_impl.h' is not supposed to be included directly. Include 'foo.h' instead.
```

PROS:

- Separation of concerns, implementation and declarations are in separate files.
- Safe guarding implementation file avoid accidental inclusion.
- The header file used to include is not bloated with implementation code.

CONS:

- As mentioned above, have to share the implementation.

**Keep declaration and definitions separate (NOT SHARING implementation)**

For not sharing code for templates, you have to define all the possible datatypes your template can be used with in .cc/.cpp file like:

```
template class foo< int >;
template class foo< double >;
```

PROS:

- Separation of concerns, implementation and declarations are in separate files.
- No need to share your implementation

CONS:

- Not too generic. Have to know before hand what is required.